# How to backup magento to another installation

Tags: php, backup, magento, e-commerce

How do i get all the info, products pics, settings, etc... from one magento install to another?

The backup feature it has don't seem to be that great.

Comment: Are you trying to move over only certain data or just blast away the second install and put in the new data? Are there custom code modifications that need to be moved as well?

Answer (score 7):

Using SSH you can take the following steps to backup and move Magento to a new Site.

Make sure you are at the root of the magento when you run the followin commands

1. Backup the MySQL Database

   > mysqldump -h DBHOST -u DBUSER -pDBPASS
   >   DBNAME > data.sql
   >
   > ```
   > DBHOST - Database host name, usually just localhost
   > DBUSER - Database user with access rights to the database 
   > DBPASS - The password for the database user 
   > DBNAME - The name of the database that Magento is using
   > ```
2. Backup the media directory with all product pics

   > tar -cvf media.tar media/*
3. Backup the app directory for the default interface

   > cd app/design/frontend/default/
   >
   > tar -cvf app.tar mytheme/

   Change mytheme with the name of your theme
4. Backup the skin directory for the default interface

   > cd skin/frontend/default/
   >
   > tar -cvf skin.tar mytheme/

   Change mytheme with the name of your theme
5. Backup the config file localed here:

   > app/etc/local.xml
6. Extract and overwrite all the files saved above to your new location

   To import the database use phpmyadmin or use this command line :

   > mysql -h DBHOST -u DBUSER -pDBPASS DBNAME < data.sql

Answer (score 0):

Magento is like any other PHP web application in this case - you need to copy all of the files in the Magento directory, and copy the database.

The Magento backup tool simply creates a backup of the database, not the files.

Answer (score 0):

subversion or git and a DB dump makes it easy...the only thing you have to change is if you move domains the config_core_resource table needs to be updated to new url and the local.xml with new db login info if needed